# Equivalent resistance between two points of the figure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

The question demands finding the equivalent resistance between points A and O. The wire running through the vertices has negligible resistance.[image]

I have tried to use symmetry but it doesnt help much. The only way seems is to apply delta star conversion but that involves very lengthy calculations. I am looking for a shorter approach.

Comment: Just use symmetry. No delta star conversion is needed. $R_{eq}= \frac{R}{4}.$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symmetry in resistor circuits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71994)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).